# Can a person write a thesis years later if illness set in?

Tags: thesis

Can a person write her thesis years later for the mere sake of doing it if illness interrupted her upon completion of graduate courses in English Literature?

Comment: I have heard of such cases.  These people may be called "ABD" (they have completed all but the dissertation).  Then, for example, they may teach in a high school for years, and finally come back to defend a thesis.

Comment: If you're asking whether it is possible at all, then the answer is "yes" because I know at least one such person. If you're asking if you, or a colleague, or any particular person can do it – we have no idea because it depends on very individual factors. Overall, it is unclear what are you precisely asking about.

Comment: "years later" is vague. 2 or 3 years? Why are you even asking? The answer is obviously "yes" (as to possibility, not feasibility in a concrete case) 30 years? Who knows? Ask the relevant decision makers, not random strangers on the internet.

Comment: 30+ years works too. Pause your PhD to become a rock star, then come back graduate. https://www.cnbc.com/2019/01/04/queen-guitarist-brian-may-is-also-an-astrophysicist.html

Answer (score 2):

It is probably possible, but would depend on the university and an advisor. Unfortunately, some places have time limits and old courses don't count anymore. But in the case of illness, it might be possible to get exceptions to such rules.

But it is a question for a particular place and a particular advisor.

But that is assuming you want a degree. You can, of course, write anything you like and possibly get it published even without a degree.

Comment: In addition to the course expiration dates, I have seen multiple universities require continuous enrollment of dissertation credits, even during a leave. They withhold your degree until you pay (in my case, not a lot, but I know of one student who had to pay several thousands).

Answer (score 2):

It is in many cases possible to suspend without penalty registration in a program for a number of legitimate reason: illness, burden of care, maternity/paternity leave, etc.  Normally this can be arranged when the student is still actively registered in the program.

If the student is no longer active, it may be possible to ask the program coordinator to reinstate registration due to such circumstances, often for a fee.

The real question is not the thesis (or the thesis topic) but the current relevance of the previous courses and thesis topic.  Some programs have a sunset clause on courses: one is required to complete the program with a set time because the knowledge accumulated in courses taken too far back has become outdated (v.g. courses on medical imaging taken 15 years ago are no longer relevant of content).